# getting keytyped from the keycode

Tags: java, keyevent, keycode

I have to send the key code in hexadecimal to a function whose job is to tell which key's code is that. For example key code in java for `CONTROL` key in hexadecimal form is `0x11`. Is there a way i can directly get the key typed ? Otherwise i have to use switch statement. But i don't want to consider it.I think that is not a smart way to do this.

Comment: The key code is supposed to identify the key; what do you want to convert it to?

Comment: @Mechanical snail key char. I want to know the key pressed/typed from that.

Comment: But the keycode already tells you which key. You mean the name of the key?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`java.awt.event.KeyEvent.getKeyText(int keyCode)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/event/KeyEvent.html#getKeyText%28int%29). According to the Javadoc: it

> Returns a String describing the keyCode, such as "HOME", "F1" or "A".